# Map orthogonal vectors to another orthogonal plane uniquely

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

Given the Cartesian vectors $\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3$ and some arbitrary vector in 3D-space $\mathbf{t}$, is it possible to define a unique mapping (matrix operator) that maps $\mathbf{e}_2$ to some $\mathbf{m}$, and some $\mathbf{e}_3$ to $\mathbf{n}$, such that $\mathbf{m} \perp \mathbf{n} \perp\mathbf{t}$? ($\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are not given)

In other words, given some $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, find $\boldsymbol{Q}\in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ such that
$$
\boldsymbol{Q}:\{ \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3\} \to \{ \mathbf{m}, \mathbf{n}\} \, ,\quad \text{s.t.}\quad \mathbf{m} \perp \mathbf{n} \perp\mathbf{t} 
$$

Is this possible to do with a single formula?, or is the only solution algortihmic in nature (test the cross product against two possible candidates, at least one won't be parallel to $\mathbf{t}$)?

Comment: Choose any $m$ orthogonal to $t$ (if $t\ne0,$ you have a whole plane of possible $m$'s), and then any $n$ orthogonal to both $t$ and $m$ (if $t,m\ne0$ you have a whole line, directed by $t\land m$).

Comment: Choosing $\mathbf{m}$ is equivalent to finding $\boldsymbol{Q}$, since then I can define $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{t} \times \mathbf{m}$. The problem is essentialy how to define $\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ with a closed formula that depends only on $\mathbf{t}$ and always works?

Comment: Yes you can choose $n=t\times m$ (as already mentionned with the [French notation  $\land$](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produit_vectoriel#Notation)). To choose $m\perp t=(a,b,c),$ you can take for instance $m=(c,0,-a)$ if $a$ or $c$ is $\ne0,$ and $(1,0,0)$ if $a=c=0.$

Comment: Thanks for the effort! But you are running into the same problem I have :) 
Namely, your solution is not absolute, but algorithmic in nature as it involves an "if" statement. Do you know of a closed function such that $f(\mathbf{t}) = \mathbf{m}$ without the need for an internal conditional statement?

Comment: If you want a function of a nonzero $t$ that *always* returns a *nonzero* $m$, [there is none](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. That is rather unfortunate :(

Comment: I actually have one solution that works, but not in some cases...
Define the normalised vector $\mathbf{t}_* = t / \| \mathbf{t} \|$, then the projection operator $\boldsymbol{Q} = \boldsymbol{I} - \mathbf{t}_* \otimes \mathbf{t}_*$ works in mapping $\{\mathrm{e}_2 , \mathrm{e}_3\}$ to $\{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{n}\}$. But the problem arises for example when $\mathbf{t} \parallel \mathbf{e}_2$, since then $\boldsymbol{Q} \mathbf{e}_2 = 0$... I thought there might be a solution for that problem somewhere, but I couldn't find anything